# How do you set periodic timers in d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

I want to run a particular function every 5 minutes. If I write code like this:

```
function f() {
    console.log("hi");
    d3.timer(f, 5*60*1000);
    return true;
}

d3.timer(f, 5*60*1000);
```

then `f` seems to run once and then never again.

I achieved the desired behavior by creating a clone of `f` called `f2`: `f` calls `d3.timer(f2)` and `f2` call `d3.timer(f)`. This seems like an ugly hack. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This sounds like a job for the standard JavaScript `setInterval()` method:

```
setInterval(f, 5*60*1000);
```

If you need it to run an animation at each invocation, that's where `d3.timer` would be useful - otherwise, the standard `setInterval` and `setTimeout` methods are likely to be easier.

Comment: Sorry if my example was unclear: in reality, the `console.log("hi")` is indeed some d3 animation code.

I'm still not sure why I'd (or anyone would) want to use `d3.timer` instead of standard Javascript timer code like `setInterval`. In fact, why does `d3.timer` even exist if we could just use `setTimeout`?

Comment: Okay, I think [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/d3-js/cKjsIPzuIoA) makes the difference clear. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 15):

I think [@nrabinowitz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13403301/1015178) is probably the best and simplest, but if you'd really like to use `d3.timer`, here's how you'd do it.

```
var interval = 1000; // one second in milliseconds

var makeCallback = function() {
    // note that we're returning a new callback function each time
    return function() {
        console.log('OH HAI!!');
        d3.timer(makeCallback(), interval);
        return true;
    }
};

d3.timer(makeCallback(), interval);
```

Your code isn't working as expected because d3.js maps timers to function instances (see the code here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/d3.v2.js#L4073), so your code was doing the following:

1. set timer with callback `f()`
2. `f()` is called after five minutes
3. `f()` logs to the console, creates a new timer which also uses `f()` as its callback, and then **cancels that timer by returning `true`**.

The code in my answer solves the problem by returning a new function instance each time.

Of course, this is way more complicated and harder to understand that just using `setInterval`, so you should do that.

Comment: for me, using a geo projection, i saw a 100 fold improvement in performance using this d3 timer technique - i.e. cpu usage went from 100% to 1% for an equivalent animation. I assume this is because an animation frame is being requested.

Comment: also, using timer ensures that when the requestAnimationFrame is available the animation doesn't run when the tab isn't in the foreground

Answer (score 1):

Looks like d3.interval is a thing, and is meant to be a replacement for setInterval: https://github.com/d3/d3-timer#interval

```
var interval = d3.timeout(callback, interval_time, optional_delay);
```